# How to insert a variable into an equation?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, calculator, equation

I have made this basic calculator that I wanted to add variables to that would translate into a certain protocol. For example, I want to set "k" to multiply the number it is attached to by 2.5 (done with "set k=2.5" as for the actual variable command). The reason I'm having trouble is due to how my code is set up and because I'm not sure how to inject the variable itself when typing the equation itself.

The code itself for the calculator so far is as follows:

```
    @echo off
    title Led's Calculator
    color 1f
    mode con: cols=36 lines=12

    rem These are all set variables that can be used in this calc.
    set k=2.5
    :top
    echo -----------------------------------
    echo Welcome to Batch Calculator by Led
    echo -----------------------------------
    echo.
    set /p sum=
    set /a ans=%sum%
    echo.
    echo = %ans%
    echo -----------------------------------
    pause
    cls
    echo Previous Answer: %ans%
    goto top
    pause
    exit
```

If anyone could tell me how to do so using K=2.5 as their example, I'd be really thankful. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: `set /a result=ans*k`

Comment: First, on using /A (arithmetic expression) each string not being a number or arithmetic operator is interpreted automatically as name of a variable. Expanding the variable with `%sum%` (immediate expansion) or `!sum!` (delayed expansion) is therefore not necessary. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read all output help pages carefully. Second, Windows command interpreter supports only arithmetic expressions using 32-bit signed integers. Floating point expressions are not supported. A multiplication with `2.5` is therefore not possible without working around this limitation.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias, for the answer, but i don't want to make ALL the answers multiplied by k. Only if I, say, typed in **4k +2**, I would want it to actually calculate it as **10+2**.

Comment: Thanks, Mofi, for your answer. Would there be any possible way of multiplying a variable by 2.5 without any major system changes?

Comment: `4k` cannot work as there is no operator, so you need to state `4*k`; as Mofi already stated, `set /A` supports **integer** arithmetics only! if there is always one fractional digit, calculate with `25` and insert the decimal dot with string manipulation afterwards; you may consider this as _fixed-point arithmetics_ -- check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38378912) as an example...

Comment: Thanks, aschipfl, for your answer. Would you mind elaborating on this string manipulation? I'm not very experienced with such thing. And yes I do realize that **4k** would return as **42.5**. Thanks for that.